# Valgrind showing memory leak? Possibly fftw related?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

I am trying to debug some code that has a memory leak, and running valgrind gives me some errors, but I am having some trouble understanding why how I am using fftw is causing the problem.

```
==1286== 44,384 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 85 of 85
==1286==    at 0x4C320A6: memalign (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1286==    by 0x6D47864: fftwf_malloc_plain (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f.so.3.5.7)
==1286==    by 0x6D48F9E: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f.so.3.5.7)
==1286==    by 0x6D4B7D7: fftwf_solvtab_exec (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f.so.3.5.7)
==1286==    by 0x6D85B60: fftwf_rdft_conf_standard (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f.so.3.5.7)
==1286==    by 0x6E0FCE0: fftwf_configure_planner (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f.so.3.5.7)
==1286==    by 0x6E13427: fftwf_the_planner (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f.so.3.5.7)
==1286==    by 0x6E0FA6C: fftwf_mkapiplan (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f.so.3.5.7)
==1286==    by 0x6E1300A: fftwf_plan_many_dft (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f.so.3.5.7)
==1286==    by 0x6E12366: fftwf_plan_dft (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f.so.3.5.7)
==1286==    by 0x6E12065: fftwf_plan_dft_1d (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f.so.3.5.7)
==1286==    by 0x666D0C2: Framework_Fft::create_plan(FFT_SIZE) (Framework_Fft.cc:228)
==1286== LEAK SUMMARY:
==1286==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1286==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1286==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1286==    still reachable: 118,440 bytes in 1,353 blocks
==1286==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

HEAP SUMMARY:
==1200==     in use at exit: 118,392 bytes in 1,353 blocks
==1200==   total heap usage: 31,167,920 allocs, 31,166,567 frees, 390,943,154,294 bytes allocated
==1200== 
==1200== Searching for pointers to 1,353 not-freed blocks
```

Framework_fft.cc, is the following

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>

#include <fftw3.h>
#include <wifi_ac/Shim/Framework_Fft.h>
#include <wifi_ac/Modem/Phy/Common/Phy_Common.h>
#include <wifi_ac/Modem/Phy/Common/Trace_Macro.h>


// XXX: Update this array when adding support for new FFT sizes.
const size_t Framework_Fft::mSizeMap[FFT_COUNT] = {64, 128, 256, 512};

Framework_Fft::Framework_Fft()
{
   FFT_SIZE max_size = get_size_enum(PHY_MAX_SZFFT);

   mpInput = (fftwf_complex*)create_buffer(max_size);
   mpIntermediate = (fftwf_complex*)create_buffer(max_size);

   {
      planner::scoped_lock lock(planner::mutex());

      // These are the supported plans for FFT.
      TRACE_LEVEL_GTEQ(TRACE_VERBOSE, "INFO in " << TRACE_COUT_METHOD_NAME << ":  Creating FFT plans.");
      // JIRA TA-183: vvvvv
      switch (max_size)
      {
         // Fall-through intentional...
         case FFT_512:
            create_plan(FFT_512);
         case FFT_256:
            create_plan(FFT_256);
         case FFT_128:
            create_plan(FFT_128);
         case FFT_64:
            create_plan(FFT_64);
            break;
      }
//      create_plan(FFT_64);
//      create_plan(FFT_128);
//      create_plan(FFT_256);
//      create_plan(FFT_512);
      // JIRA TA-183: ^^^^^
      TRACE_LEVEL_GTEQ(TRACE_VERBOSE, "INFO in " << TRACE_COUT_METHOD_NAME << ":  FFT plans created.");
   }
}

Framework_Fft::~Framework_Fft()
{
   // JIRA TA-183: vvvvv
   FFT_SIZE max_size = get_size_enum(PHY_MAX_SZFFT);
   {
      planner::scoped_lock lock(planner::mutex());
      switch (max_size)
      {
         // Fall-through intentional...
         case FFT_512:
            destroy_plan(FFT_512);
         case FFT_256:
            destroy_plan(FFT_256);
         case FFT_128:
            destroy_plan(FFT_128);
         case FFT_64:
            destroy_plan(FFT_64);
            break;
      }

//      destroy_plan(FFT_64);
//      destroy_plan(FFT_128);
//      destroy_plan(FFT_256);
//      destroy_plan(FFT_512);
      // JIRA TA-183: ^^^^^
      TRACE_LEVEL_GTEQ(TRACE_VERBOSE, "INFO in " << TRACE_COUT_METHOD_NAME << ":  FFT plans destroyed.");
   }

   if (mpInput)
   {
      fftwf_free(mpInput);
      mpInput = NULL;
   }

   if (mpIntermediate)
   {
      fftwf_free(mpIntermediate);
      mpIntermediate = NULL;
   }
};

framework_complex_internal*
Framework_Fft::create_buffer(FFT_SIZE size)
{
   fftwf_complex* fftwf_buffer = NULL;
   bool error = false;
   if (size >= FFT_COUNT)
   {
      TRACE_LEVEL_GTEQ(TRACE_ERROR, "ERROR in " << TRACE_COUT_METHOD_NAME << ":  FFT_SIZE of " << size << " not supported.");
      error = true;
   }

   if (sizeof(framework_complex_internal) != sizeof(fftwf_complex))
   {
      TRACE_LEVEL_GTEQ(TRACE_ERROR, "ERROR in " << TRACE_COUT_METHOD_NAME << ":  Type framework_complex_internal size not compatible with fftwf_complex.");
      error = true;
   }

   if (!error)
   {
      fftwf_buffer =
         (fftwf_complex*)fftwf_malloc(sizeof(fftwf_complex) * mSizeMap[size]);

      if (NULL == fftwf_buffer)
      {
         TRACE_LEVEL_GTEQ(TRACE_ERROR, "ERROR in " << TRACE_COUT_METHOD_NAME << ":  Memory allocation using fftwf_malloc failed.");
         TRACE_LEVEL_GTEQ(TRACE_ERROR, "         NULL pointer is being returned.");
         error = true;
      }
   }

   if (error)
   {
      TRACE_LEVEL_GTEQ(TRACE_ERROR, "ERROR(s) occurred in " << TRACE_COUT_METHOD_NAME << ".");
//      printf("%s: Returning NULL\n", TRACE_COUT_METHOD_NAME);
   }

   return (framework_complex_internal*)fftwf_buffer;
   cout << fftwf_buffer;
}

framework_complex_internal*
Framework_Fft::create_buffer(size_t size)
{
   FFT_SIZE fft_size = get_size_enum(size);
   return create_buffer(fft_size);
}

void
Framework_Fft::free_buffer(framework_complex_internal* buffer)
{
   if (buffer)
   {
      fftwf_free(buffer);
      buffer = NULL;
   }
}

void
Framework_Fft::FftComplex(
   FFT_SIZE size,
   const framework_complex_internal* pInputBufferComplex,
   framework_complex_internal* pOutputBufferComplex)
{
   bool freeinput = false;
   framework_complex_internal* input = (framework_complex_internal*)pInputBufferComplex;
   TRACE_LEVEL_GTEQ(TRACE_VERBOSE, "INFO in " << TRACE_COUT_METHOD_NAME << ":  FftComplex of size " << (int)mSizeMap[size] << ".");
   // We may need to align the buffer that is input to fftwf.
   if ((uint64_t)pInputBufferComplex % 16 != 0)
   {
      TRACE_LEVEL_GTEQ(TRACE_INFO, "WARNING in " << TRACE_COUT_METHOD_NAME << ":  FftComplex - Input buffer does not appear to be aligned.");
      input = create_buffer(size);
      memcpy(
         input,
         pInputBufferComplex,
         sizeof(framework_complex_internal) * mSizeMap[size]);
      freeinput = true;
   }

   fftwf_execute_dft(
      mFftwfPlans[size], (fftwf_complex*)input, (fftwf_complex*)mpIntermediate);

   size_t szHalfFftSize = mSizeMap[size] / 2;

   // First half from fftwf_execute goes into 2nd half of output buffer
   memcpy(
      pOutputBufferComplex + szHalfFftSize,
      mpIntermediate,
      szHalfFftSize * sizeof(fftwf_complex));

   // Second half of fftwf_execute goes into first half of output buffer.
   memcpy(
      pOutputBufferComplex,
      mpIntermediate + szHalfFftSize,
      szHalfFftSize * sizeof(fftwf_complex));

   if (freeinput)
   {
      free_buffer(input);
   }
}

void
Framework_Fft::FftComplex(
   size_t size,
   const framework_complex_internal* pInputBufferComplex,
   framework_complex_internal* pOutputBufferComplex)
{
   FFT_SIZE fft_size = get_size_enum(size);
   FftComplex(fft_size, pInputBufferComplex, pOutputBufferComplex);
}

FFT_SIZE
Framework_Fft::get_size_enum(size_t size)
{
   FFT_SIZE fft_size = (FFT_SIZE)(FFT_COUNT - 1);
   bool size_found = false;

   for (int i = 0; i < FFT_COUNT; i++)
   {
      if (mSizeMap[i] == size)
      {
         fft_size = (FFT_SIZE)i;
         size_found = true;
         break;
      }
   }

   if (!size_found)
   {
      TRACE_LEVEL_GTEQ(TRACE_INFO, "WARNING in " << TRACE_COUT_METHOD_NAME << ":  FFT size " << size << " is invalid.");
      TRACE_LEVEL_GTEQ(TRACE_INFO, "           Performing FFT of size " << mSizeMap[fft_size] << " instead.");
   }
   return fft_size;
}

void
Framework_Fft::create_plan(FFT_SIZE fft_size)
{
   mFftwfPlans[fft_size] = fftwf_plan_dft_1d(
      mSizeMap[fft_size], mpInput, mpIntermediate, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_PATIENT);
}

void
Framework_Fft::destroy_plan(FFT_SIZE fft_size)
{
   if (mFftwfPlans[fft_size])
   {
      fftwf_destroy_plan(mFftwfPlans[fft_size]);
   }
}

// Added by mwk 01/10/2020 
void fftwf_cleanup(void);
```

I believe I am creating, destroying and deallocating as required.  Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: did you make sure there are all initialized ?

Comment: Could you show your code, please? Preferably in the form of a [mcve]. We are not mind readers. We cannot reason about code we cannot see/test.

Comment: Where in this line does `mdBFS_GainOffset` come from? I can't see it passed in or defined anywhere: `pBurstStateParams->PhysicalConfigParams.mdBFS_GainOffset = mdBFS_GainOffset;`

Comment: Those variables should be passed in by the user via a .ini file.  I should Cout each variable to be sure it is passed down before the line is called

Comment: @mwk088 - apologies, I see it's a member variable (it's been a while since I've done C++ and Hungarian notation!). And yes, you should check these values if they are coming from an `ini` file. It's good to use `assert` to check your code while developing it.

Comment: I reran valgrind and got a few more errors...one noticeably has to do with fftwf

Comment: I now believe my memory leak is coming from the usage of fftwf.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using an up to date version of Valgrind.

The problem variable is probably either a double or a long long.

You can use either gdb or client request macros to check if individual memory addresses are initialised.

Alternatively, if your app is easy to compile, you can just add some dummy statements just to trigger Valgrind's error detection, something like this

```
if (SignalPower_linear_min == 0.0)
    ;
if (pBurstStateParams->PhysicalConfigParams.mFullScale_linear == 0.0)
    ;
```

Once you have isolated the uninitialised variable you need to debug backwards up the callstack to find out why.

Comment: Thank you.  I have valgrind-3.13.0.  I will look into the suggestions you have made.  I did do a Cout statement on the variables and it seems they are initialized, the only one that does not rely on the ini file, and is instead calculated. 
answered 22 hours ago

`// We obtain the linear signal strength as calculated by the 802.11b PLCP processing.
   float SignalPower_linear_min = State_Dsss_Plcp.signalStrength();`